# Change M2_REPO eclipse var with something else when executing mvn eclipse:eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Is there a way or a pom configuration that when I do mvn eclipse:eclipse it will generate a .classpath file with a different variable name other than M2_REPO?

instead of

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
```

I need

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="SHARED_LIB/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
```

Comment: Do not use eclipse:eclipse anymore is long time retired. Better use import of Eclipse itself via m2e ...

Comment: I don't want to but I am using RAD v8.5 and it doesn't have a maven plugin. I can't install it without putting myself into hassle asking admin to install it for me, and it needs an approval. All I can do is download  maven and execute it in the command line.

Comment: I can really recommend it and use a WebSphere Plugin for Eclipse...instead of using such an old version of RAD...makes life easier...